# R ggplot (Code below) Trying to remove extra space on the right side of BoxPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, boxplot

I am trying to remove the extra space on the right side of my boxplot. I have not been able to find a solution.

The letters on the x-axis represent different factors. In the data set I have A, B,C,D,OH88119, and NA. NA represents missing data. Is it possible that is causing the empty space to appear?

```
    YEAR    LOC ROW BLOCK   PLOT    RATING  R_Source    QTL.SOURCE
 2  2017    Unit2   1   1   6302    6   A   A
 3  2017    Unit2   1   1   6305    4   C   C
 5  2017    Unit2   2   1   6331    4   C   C
 6  2017    Unit2   2   1   6332    4   C   C
 7  2017    Unit2   2   1   6333    4   B   B
 12 2017    Unit2   4   1   6368    5   D   D
 13 2017    Unit2   4   1   6369    3   A   A
 14 2017    Unit2   4   1   6370    5   D   D
 16 2017    Unit2   5   1   6374    5   A   A
 18 2017    Unit2   5   1   6378    4   B   B
 19 2017    Unit2   6   1   6404    4   D   D
 20 2017    Unit2   6   1   6405    5   C   C
 21 2017    Unit2   6   1   6406    6   D   D
 23 2017    Unit2   6   1   6408    4   D   D
 24 2017    Unit2   7   1   6409    3   A   A
 25 2017    Unit2   7   1   6410    na  D   D
 26 2017    Unit2   7   1   6411    7   A   A
 31 2017    Unit2   8   1   6442    8   D   D
 32 2017    Unit2   8   1   6443    4   B   B
 33 2017    Unit2   9   1   6445    6   B   B
 34 2017    Unit2   9   1   6446    6   C   C
 36 2017    Unit2   9   1   6450    4   A   A
 39 2017    Unit2   10  1   6478    4   A   A
 41 2017    Unit2   10  1   6480    4   B   B
 42 2017    Unit2   11  1   6482    7   D   D
 43 2017    Unit2   11  1   6483    3   A   A
 44 2017    Unit2   11  1   6484    9   B   B
 45 2017    Unit2   12  1   6512    4   A   A
 47 2017    Unit2   12  1   6514    6   C   C
 49 2017    Unit2   12  1   6516    6   B   B
 51 2017    Unit2   13  1   6518    5   C   C
 52 2017    Unit2   13  1   6519    7   B   B
 53 2017    Unit2   13  1   6520    7   B   B
 54 2017    Unit2   13  1   6521    4   B   B
 56 2017    Unit2   14  1   6549    NA  D   D
 57 2017    Unit2   14  1   6550    6   A   A
 59 2017    Unit2   14  1   6552    5   NA  SA
 61 2017    Unit2   1   2   6308    4   A   A
178 2017    Unit2   4   1   6371    9   OH88119 NA
179 2017    Unit2   9   1   6448    9   OH88119 NA
180 2017    Unit2   4   2   6365    7   OH88119 NA
181 2017    Unit2   5   2   6381    9   OH88119 NA
182 2017    Unit2   3   3   6349    5   OH88119 NA
183 2017    Unit2   4   3   6359    7   OH88119 NA
```

Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.

Below is my code:

```
BC1S3boxplot <- ggplot(BC1S3, aes(R_Source,DISEASERATING))
BC1S3plot <- BC1S3boxplot + theme_bw()+
geom_boxplot(fill=c("red","green","blue","purple","yellow"))+
labs(x=expression(Sample~Source),y=expression(Horsfall-Barrat~Score),
title=expression(italic(X)~field~BC1S3~vs~X))+
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("A","B","C","D","OH88119"))+
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1,8))+ 
theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=10),axis.text.x=element_text(size = 10),
axis.title=element_text(size=10),title=element_text(size=10))
BC1S3plot
```

Boxplot image here

[image: Boxplot]

[marco's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8mOp.png)

Comment: Try  `ggplot(na.omit(BC1S3), aes ...`. The "empty space" is probably caused by the NAs you mentioned. To provide an accurate answer you need to show us your `BC1S3` data

Comment: I have attached a snippet of the data. I would also like to add, that this data was subsetted from an original data set that had 10 factors (A,HA,B,HB,C,HC...etc) in R_Source. After subsetting the factors still show up when I use str(BC1S3), but they actually don't appear in the data set.

Comment: @SRivero let me know if I still was not clear. Thank you!

Comment: As @MarcoSandri mentioned, I can't reproduce your plot, it is working fine for me

Comment: @SRivero ok thanks! I need to figure out what is wrong... I checked the data and I didn't find anything wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us your `BC1S3` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. See below:

```
df <- read.table(text='
 ID  YEAR    LOC ROW BLOCK   PLOT    RATING  R_Source    QTL.SOURCE
 2  2017    Unit2   1   1   6302    6   A   A
 3  2017    Unit2   1   1   6305    4   C   C
 5  2017    Unit2   2   1   6331    4   C   C
 6  2017    Unit2   2   1   6332    4   C   C
 7  2017    Unit2   2   1   6333    4   B   B
 12 2017    Unit2   4   1   6368    5   D   D
 13 2017    Unit2   4   1   6369    3   A   A
 14 2017    Unit2   4   1   6370    5   D   D
 16 2017    Unit2   5   1   6374    5   A   A
 18 2017    Unit2   5   1   6378    4   B   B
 19 2017    Unit2   6   1   6404    4   D   D
 20 2017    Unit2   6   1   6405    5   C   C
 21 2017    Unit2   6   1   6406    6   D   D
 23 2017    Unit2   6   1   6408    4   D   D
 24 2017    Unit2   7   1   6409    3   A   A
 25 2017    Unit2   7   1   6410    NA  D   D
 26 2017    Unit2   7   1   6411    7   A   A
 31 2017    Unit2   8   1   6442    8   D   D
 32 2017    Unit2   8   1   6443    4   B   B
 33 2017    Unit2   9   1   6445    6   B   B
 34 2017    Unit2   9   1   6446    6   C   C
 36 2017    Unit2   9   1   6450    4   A   A
 39 2017    Unit2   10  1   6478    4   A   A
 41 2017    Unit2   10  1   6480    4   B   B
 42 2017    Unit2   11  1   6482    7   D   D
 43 2017    Unit2   11  1   6483    3   A   A
 44 2017    Unit2   11  1   6484    9   B   B
 45 2017    Unit2   12  1   6512    4   A   A
 47 2017    Unit2   12  1   6514    6   C   C
 49 2017    Unit2   12  1   6516    6   B   B
 51 2017    Unit2   13  1   6518    5   C   C
 52 2017    Unit2   13  1   6519    7   B   B
 53 2017    Unit2   13  1   6520    7   B   B
 54 2017    Unit2   13  1   6521    4   B   B
 56 2017    Unit2   14  1   6549    NA  D   D
 57 2017    Unit2   14  1   6550    6   A   A
 59 2017    Unit2   14  1   6552    5   NA  SA
 61 2017    Unit2   1   2   6308    4   A   A
178 2017    Unit2   4   1   6371    9   OH88119 NA
179 2017    Unit2   9   1   6448    9   OH88119 NA
180 2017    Unit2   4   2   6365    7   OH88119 NA
181 2017    Unit2   5   2   6381    9   OH88119 NA
182 2017    Unit2   3   3   6349    5   OH88119 NA
183 2017    Unit2   4   3   6359    7   OH88119 NA
', header=T)

BC1S3boxplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=R_Source, y=RATING))
BC1S3plot <- BC1S3boxplot + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=R_Source)) +
labs(x=expression(Sample~Source),y=expression(Horsfall-Barrat~Score),
title=expression(italic(X)~field~BC1S3~vs~X))+
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("A","B","C","D","OH88119"))+
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1,10))+ 
theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=10),axis.text.x=element_text(size = 10),
axis.title=element_text(size=10),title=element_text(size=10))+theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: It is probably those unused factor levels.  Try `df$R_Source <-
 droplevels(df$R_Source)` before you run the code.

Comment: @MarcoSandri I copied your code and substituted df for my data set I didn't get it to work. I will add the image to the top.

Comment: @MarcoSandri ok let me recheck my code. below the my first graph I attached the image the came up. thanks for your help!

Comment: @EduardoBernal First: check in your dataset if you have any "na" value. I find one in your RATING variable and I substituted (by hand) with NA.

Comment: @MarcoSandri found the problem. in the second part of the data set I had another R_Source named "S". So I removed it. thanks for running the code for me.